# How to loop through List<Integer[]>

Tags: java, arrays, list

I have a `List<Integer[]> al`. (an array of arrays)
How would I access every element of `al` freely? The only way I know how to access all the elements is like:

```
for (Integer[] set : al) {
    for (Integer number : set) {
        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

My issue is that I need to access `al` seamlessly such as

```
al[0].get(0);
```

Comment: `al`is a List. No an array. So you can't use `[]` to access its elements. You must use `get()`. And `al.get(0)`is an array, not a List, So you can't access its elements using `get()`. You need to use `[]`: `al.get(0)[0]`.

Comment: Uhm ... `al.get(0)[0]`?

Comment: *"(an array of arrays)"* No, that's a *list* of arrays.

Comment: This is my first time using stack overflow... I did not think it would be so fast. Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 1):

### List vs Array

Lists an arrays are two completely different data structures.

An array is a very fast and compact solution for storing data. The big disadvantage is that it is **fixed in size**. That means that you need to tell it its size when you initially create it and that it is impossible to increase or reduce the size from there on. You can only set values, but not add or remove values.

A list is a collection that can **grow and shrink** dynamically in its size. So you can `add` and `remove` values, unlike in an array. The `ArrayList` class is a very efficient implementation of a list that uses arrays under the hood (it is a list, not an array). Lists themselves are interfaces that offer a lot of nice methods. See its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

---

### Array access

Accessing elements at a specific index in an array is done using `[]`:

```
Foo element = array[i];
```

---

### List access

Doing the same in a `List` is done using the `get(int index)` method (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#get(int))):

```
Foo element = list.get(i);
```

---

### List of arrays

What you have is not an array of arrays (which would be `arrayOfArrays[i][j]`) but a `List` of arrays. So the correct access is:

```
Foo element = list.get(i)[j];
```

Or, step by step:

```
Foo[] array = list.get(i);
Foo element = array[j];
```

---

### Solution

Unfortunately you did not really provide an explanation of what exactly you want to do with the data, nor how exactly you want to work with it. So I can only give you a small snippet that showcases how to print the elements using index-based loops:

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < al.get(j).length; j++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(j)[i]);
    }
}
```

---

### Notes

For this specific usage, two enhanced for loops would be much easier to read:

```
for (Integer[] values : al) {
    for (Integer value : values) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }
}
```

Please note that `al` is not a good variable name, as it is not self-explanatory. Try to give it a name that represents its purpose, regarding the contained data.

If possible, avoid using `Integer[]` and instead go for `int[]`. It will be faster and consume less memory if you use the primitive instead of the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < al.get(i).length; j++) {
        System.out.println(al.get(i)[j]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This may help you**

```
    Integer[] integerArrayOne = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    Integer[] integerArrayTwo = new Integer[]{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23};

    List<Integer[]> listOfIntegerArray = new ArrayList<>();

    listOfIntegerArray.add(integerArrayOne);
    listOfIntegerArray.add(integerArrayTwo);

    for (Integer[] array : listOfIntegerArray) {
        for (Integer integerValue : array) {
            System.out.print(integerValue + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

> Output :

```
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
    11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Array and List both support Random access, the elements can be directly accessed by specifying the index of element.

For List class , get(int index) method is available. 
For array, array[i] where i is the index of the element.

So, if you wish to parse all the elements, you will have to use 2 loops as specified in your question itself.

But, if you are fine with simplifying the structure to single list, and it can be parsed using a single loop.

Using java8, 
    
    `List<Integer[]> ip = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> output =
    ip.stream().flatMap(x->Arrays.stream(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Using Java7 or lower,
     
     `for(Integer[] i : ip) {
       output.addAll(Arrays.asList(i)); 
     }`

Now, it can be accessed in a single loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of `Integer` arrays, so you can access an element as

```
al.get(0)[0];
```